# Is there any in-universe explanation of Palpatine, Skywalker, and Tarkin coming from the same sector?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I've just finished Luceno's *Tarkin* and feel intrigued by Palpatine's hint that [Anakin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tatooine), [Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eriadu), and [him](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Naboo) being born on more or less neighboring systems is not a coincidence. What is the reason, then?

I'm interested in an answer of **any** degree of canonicity.

EDIT: After looking at the map it's becoming clear that the neighborhood can be called *close* only from a certain point of view.

Comment: The answer is midi-chlorians. No really. The answer actually *is* midi-chlorians.

Comment: @Richard - Noooooooooooo!

Comment: @DVK - [Au contraire](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/54653619.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In-universe, Palpatine is referring to the [Will of the Living Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Living_Force), a sort of Galactic consciousness that <s>keeps things narratively neat</s> guides force-sensitive people to where they need to be.

> **Qui-Gon:** *"Without the [midi-chlorians](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian), life could not exist, and we would have
>   no knowledge of the Force. **They continually speak to us, telling us
>   the will of the Force. When you learn to quiet your mind, you'll hear
>   them speaking to you."*** - <sub><sup>Star Wars: The Phantom Menace</sup></sub>

It's this force that [leads Qui-Gon Jinn to Anakin Skywalker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72434/20774), that leads Rey to the Millennium Falcon, that leads Luke to the droids, that drops Luke's lightsaber into Rey's lap, etc etc. This is what the Emperor feels is responsible for the unnatural chain of coincidences around the key players in the Empire.

> *“Do you not find it intriguing that both you and Moff Tarkin have ties to the very planet where this newly discovered cache of jamming devices has been found? Tarkin, to quash Dooku’s Shadowfeeds, and you—in one of your first missions, I seem to recall—to effect an execution. **Or perhaps you feel that no connections exist, that this is mere coincidence.”**
>   Vader knew the reply. **“There are no coincidences, Master.”**
>
>   “And that, my apprentice, is why Murkhana matters to us. **Because the dark side of the Force has for whatever reason brought that world to our attention once more—as you should well understand.”*** - <sub><sup>[Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Yeah, that's the excerpt. The Force conspiracy theory as it were. Is e.g. Darth Plagueis' hand in it, as well?

Comment: @DeerHunter - Your guess is as good as mine. I'm going to say "maybe".

Comment: -1000 because you mentioned the M-word

Comment: @DVK - Finally, a question where the answer actually is *the m-word*. I'm actually really chuffed that watching Phantom Menace eventually paid off.